# Monotouch: Play background audio with iPhone Simulator

Tags: audio, background, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

First sorry for poor English!

I set this value at plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

and use AVAudioPlayer to play audio, but when play audio, the play icon in the statusbar don't show and when push home button i can't hear any audio and when come back to app the audio playing and i can hear audio, but if i pushed home button about 10 second befor, audio will playing at background that i can't hear any thing until reactive app and lost about 10 second of audio that i can't hear.

Answer (score 2):

When i last checked, background audio testing is a feature that you can only get on a hardware device. This makes sense as you cannot test for call interuptions etc. on the simulator.